# coercing MonoObject to MonoClass (where a method call returns a type)

Tags: .net, mono, embedded

I have a method call that returns `Type`.  I want to make use of the type and do some reflection from C++.  Have code like this:

```
MonoClass* klass = (MonoClass*)mono_runtime_invoke (...);
```

I am pretty sure that the casting to `MonoClass*` is not appropriate.  The function returns a `MonoObject*`.  How do I coerce the MonoObject* containing a reference to `Type` to `MonoClass*`.   I want to be able to be able to call:

```
mono_class_get_properties (type, &iter)
```

iteratively, later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1

If you have an access to the .NET code, the simpliest way is to return the type's TypeHandle. In the native code, you can access the `MonoType`by unboxing the result of the invocation.

In C#:

```
static IntPtr GetUnderlyingTypeHandle()
{
    Type type;
    // ...
    return type.TypeHandle.Value;
}
```

In native code:

```
MonoMethod *method = ...; // Retrieve the method to call
MonoObject *obj = mono_runtime_invoke(method, NULL, NULL, NULL);
MonoType *underlyingType = *(MonoType **) mono_object_unbox(obj);
```

### Solution 2

If you cannot change the .NET code, then you have to call the `TypeHandle` and `Value` getters in native code.

Answer (score 1):

In the C# code you can return type.TypeHandle (of course you need to change the method signature's return type) and then you can unbox the mono_runtime_invoke() return value (which is always an object) and cast the pointer to MonoType*. Once you have the MonoType*, you can get the MonoClass* with mono_class_from_mono_type() or mono_type_get_class(), as appropriate.

If you can't change the C# code, you can mono_runtime_invoke() the get_TypeHandle() method from C as well.

Comment: you missed the step of returning TypeHandle.Value as IntPtr.  Returning TypeHandle and unboxing will point to the wrong thing.  Nevertheless pointed in the right direction.

Comment: While you're correct that it's better to use the Value property since the implementation could change some day (though in this case it's very unlikely), my suggestion still works, since you would be unboxing a RuntimeTypeHandle struct which just contains a IntPtr field and unboxing it in the C code is exactly the same as unboxing a bare IntPtr value: if you had different results you did something else wrong.